# NextJS Middleware Server Error: Attempt to export a nullable value for "TextDecoderStream"

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, middleware, bun

I have set up a simple nextjs application with bun (version `1.0.4`, `bun create next-app`) with app routing (nextjs `13.5.4`) and a source directory. I wanted to include a middleware that only allows traffic from certain IPs however if I have the `middleware.ts` file in the `/src` directory (where it should be according to the docs) no matter what's in the file I get the following error:

```
Error: Attempt to export a nullable value for "TextDecoderStream"
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
defineProperties
file:<PROJECT>/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js
addPrimitives
file:<PROJECT>/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js
extend
file:<PROJECT>/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js
new VM
file:<PROJECT>/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js
new EdgeVM
file:<PROJECT>/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js
<anonymous>
file:<PROJECT>/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/sandbox/context.js (196:64)
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/node_modules
/public
/src
/src/app
/src/lib
/src/middleware.ts
/<config_and_env_files...>
/bun.lockb
/next-env.d.ts
/next.config.js
/package.json
/tsconfig.json
```

Is there any way to fix this error so that I can whitelist IPs or is there a better way to whitelist IPs so that I can go around the problem?
I tried googling the issue but there is not much on the topic of this error.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me on PopOs

1. Install nodejs - make sure you get the latest stable version
2. Install npm
3. cd into project
4. Run `npm run dev` and stop it
5. Run `bun run dev`

Bun have not implemented `TextDecoderStream`. They say
"It’s faster to just make all the APIs accept strings instead of having a separate encoder/decoder stream pass through input." in [this tweet thread](https://twitter.com/jarredsumner/status/1700962788477399323)

I'd love to know why this works.

Comment: Step 4 isn't necessary.  Step 2 isn't necessary either because npm is included in Node.js installations

Answer (score 1):

Bun does not yet implement `TextDecoderStream`.  You can follow its implementation on [Bun's roadmap](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/159).

In [Bun's Next.js guide](https://bun.sh/guides/ecosystem/nextjs) they make this clear

> The Next.js App Router currently relies on Node.js APIs that Bun does not yet implement. The guide below uses Bun to initialize a project and install dependencies, but it uses Node.js to run the dev server.

So that's why the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750715/3813155) "works".  It's still using the Node.js runtime.  You have to pass the `--bun` flag to have it use the Bun runtime